# "I specialize in system programming by using C++"

Tags: grammaticality

> I specialize in system programming by using C++.

This is a résumé of an applicant. Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: If you don't know the answer, then you certainly shouldn't be counting it against him or her.

Comment: It's a bit short, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cout << "It's not great, but surely you're not employing them for their english skill. :P";

The way it's phrased (esp. "by") suggests that they specialised by using C++; that their use of c++ has made them a specialist. For example: "I specialised in tropical medicine by studying for another year at University X".

It's almost certainly not what they're trying to say: something like "I specialise in system programming in C++" or "with C++" or "using C++" would probably be better, or even "I specialise in C++ system programming."

But really, it's very nitpicky.

Comment: -1 Nice. Where is the answer, though?

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but not very flattering of the candidate if interpreted strictly. Other, similar, also grammatically correct sentences, would give a better impression of the candidate, and may well be what the candidate intended to say.

Answer (score 3):

The grammar is technically OK, but the phrase "using c++" suggests its author is a neophyte. People who actually do systems programming for a living usually say that they write C++.

Indeed, this *is* nitpicky, but writing software could be said to be nitpicking *to its extreme*. The people who eventually select candidates for interviews are generally software people, so they're bound to nitpick at least a little.

Comment: The first clause of your first sentence is not categorical. The rest is commentary. Please try to provide cut-and-dried answers as far as possible, along with authentic reference(s) where possible to qualify as a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical but awkward. And the way it's phrased makes the meaning ambiguous.

Is it saying that the applicant is specializing by using C++? Or is this the applicant's way of merely saying that he or she uses C++ when system programming?

Perhaps it would be better expressed the following way:

> I specialize in system programming with C++.